# Why is jQuery.get() changing my URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the below code where I am simply getting a resource with an Ajax jQuery call..

```
 $.get({
            url: "http://jennifer-lawrence/mygirl/FreeTonight.php",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(b) {
                a(b, b.signature)
            }
        })
```

When I fire this, it fails and when I look in the Network tab of Chrome dev tools, I see that the request is going out to..

```
 http://jennifer-lawrence/mygirl/[object%20Object]
```

and of course the server returns a 404.

But if I change the "$.get" in the above code to "$.ajax" then it works fine.

What's up with that??

Comment: change `$.get({` to `$.ajax({`

Comment: $.get takes a URL as it's first parameter (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) rather than an object. Hence why $.ajax works.

Comment: `$.get("http://jennifer-lawrence/mygirl/FreeTonight.php").then(function(response) { console.log('response', response); }).fail(function(error) { console.log('error', error); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the docs: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

`$.get` does not take an object in the same way that `$.ajax` does. Likely because it is a shortcut to be able to quickly write `$.get(url)`.

Per the docs your code should be:

```
 $.get("http://jennifer-lawrence/mygirl/FreeTonight.php", Null,
        function(b) {
            a(b, b.signature)
        }
,'json');
```

Or just change `$.get` to `$.ajax`, problem solved.

**Actually**

You can pass an object to `$.get` in version >=1.12 and >=2.2. So your example would work if you update your jQuery version to one of those. But `type: 'GET'` is completely redundant.

Answer (score 1):

`[object%20Object]` is what you get when you take a plain object, convert it to a string, and then URL encode it.

`http://jennifer-lawrence/mygirl/[object%20Object]` looks like you are on `http://jennifer-lawrence/mygirl/` and then try to access the relative URI `[object%20Object]`

You would get this if you passed `{ some: object }` as if it was a string representation of a URL.

---

Now see [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). There are two ways you can call `get`:

> `jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )` version added 1.0

and

> `jQuery.get( [settings ] )` version added: 1.12/2.2

You are using the second method, but it is acting like you are using the first method.

You must be using an **old** version of jQuery which does not support the second method.

Either use the first method or upgrade jQuery.